# RMSEA confidence interval interpretation

Tags: structural-equation-modeling, path-model, interpretation

Using Amos for a multi-group path analysis, my model of choice, the "measurement weights" model has an RMSEA value of .033 a LO value of .000, a Hi value of .065, and PCLOSE value of .784. Is it an issue that this interval includes 0 as the LO value? Or how is this interpreted?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Welcome to CrossValidated.

RMSEA is a measure of approximate fit - if it's below a certain value, the fit is considered OK. Trouble is, it's a sample statistic, like the mean, and we'd like to know about the population parameter, not the sample statistic.

In a regular null hypothesis test, we're usually trying to test against zero - zero means no effect. For RMSEA, we're not trying to test against 0 - we'd usually be happy with that, as we'd be happy with 0.01, 0.02, 0.03, etc.

What we wouldn't be happy with is values (much) above 0.05. The upper interval goes about 0.05, which isn't great (but is OK, because the actual estimate is below). PCLOSE provides the p-value of the null hypothesis that the estimate (0.033) is below 0.05. This is clearly not approaching significance - you can therefore not reject the null hypothesis that your RMSEA is below 0.05 - which is a good thing.

(Note: I don't know what value AMOS uses -I'm guessing 0.05).

(Also note: This is rarely reported.)